# how to get the image from imageview for posting through bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

**XML where image view is there**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="101dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:src="@drawable/image" />


</LinearLayout>
```

---

**in oncreate i have**

```
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

**My Question**::

**then for Bitmap for posting how to get the image from image view**

```
Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(------?----------);
```

Comment: On way is you can use the `setdrawingcacheenable` option to capture the image of imageView and convert it into bitmap and then share it.

Comment: @ GrlsHu ........ How this is done ... can you show an example as ur answer

Comment: @Goldee: Reviews take time. We don't want to use the precious time of users reviewing minor edits. Please make only substantial edits.

Comment: @ juergen d I think this both tags are relevant and important to the problem which I have added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Bitmap bitmapOrg = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this way:

```
Bitmap bm;

BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) yourimageview.getDrawable();
bm = drawable.getBitmap();
```

Answer (score 1):

for getting Drawable from imageView use:

```
ImageVIew.getDrawable()
```

If you want to get inputstream from the drawable use following:

```
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable);
Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable .getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] imageInByte = stream.toByteArray();
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageInByte);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `ImageView` set the option to `true` first and the save that image into sdcard after converting it to bitmap and then share that image.

Try as below:

```
          imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
          m_ivproimg.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = m_ivproimg.getDrawingCache();

         //Save image into sdcard and given name randomly.   
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File newDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
        newDir.mkdirs();
        Random gen = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = gen.nextInt(n);
        String fotoname = "photo-" + n + ".jpg";
        File file = new File(newDir, fotoname);
        String s = file.getAbsolutePath();

        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```